# scanf: template with macro (#define constant) inside

Tags: c, scanf

I have a bit of code like here:

```
#define MAXSIZE 100

int main() {
    char str[MAXSIZE+1];
    scanf("%100s", str);
    ...
```

The problem is I still have "magic number" 100, although defined MAXSIZE.
Is there a way to properly "insert" MAXSIZE into scanf format string? (pure C, c-99 standart)

Comment: do you have to use scanf? if no, try `fgets()`

Answer (score 3):

There is, but you'd be better off using `fgets()`:

```
if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin) != NULL) {
    // process input
}
```

The good thing about this (apart from an undoubted readability boost) is that `fgets()` takes care of the size *correctly,* i. e. it accounts for the terminating 0 character (which `scanf()` doesn't), so you don't have to hack around with adding one to the size when declaring your buffer. It also always NUL-terminates the array for you. Way less error prone.

---

As to the original question: try the usual "stringify" trick:

```
#define REAL_STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) REAL_STRINGIFY(x)

scanf("%" STRINGIFY(MAXSIZE) "s", str);
```

But this is very ugly, isn't it?

Comment: Very ugly! No one want to even think about it.

Comment: @haccks but I like it :), one ways is OP can declare a new macro `#define MAX "100"`

Comment: @haccks Exactly. It's disgusting.

Comment: 1. fgets is not the same that scanf("%s", for example scanf stops on whitespaces. Call multiply times to fgets (with whitespaces check) looks like potentially less performance solution. 2. stringify is really ugly :). But thanks, I didnt know about such trick.

Comment: @Nyxo With a 100-character buffer size, it's very likely that OP wanted to get an entire line. In fact, the "stop at space" behavior of `scanf()` is unintuitive and I even go as far as calling it erroneous. As to the performance: who cares? I/O is already as slow as heck. One more or less function call doesn't matter. If the bottleneck in one's code is keyboard input, then that's something seriously <s>f***</s> screwed up.

Comment: @H2CO3 I simplify question, in real project we have fscanf from file-like input pipe, and MAXSIZE is not 100 :) . So performance *may* be important. "stop-at-space" behavior is surely needed too.

Comment: @Nyxo In real world, we solve the problems that actually exist. Here, OP is reading the standard input. Nothing else. No one will type fast enough for `fgets()` to become slow enough. And anyway, what if it's slow? Seriously, who cares? It's safe, and that's order of magnitudes more important. The stop-at-space behavior is not *needed* either. If you can read in a whole line, then you can also parse it using `strchr()` or `strtok_r()` or whatever -- and that's undoubtedly better than relying on the I/O function to do it. That's just abuse of the I/O library.