# Stack infix to postfix

Tags: c

My code runs well to my surprise!!
The only problem is that whenever I use a bracketed infix input it comes out a 'J' at the end of postfix expression !! Any suggestions??
Here the algorithm is the basic one all expressions are getting converted and all is right but the tailing 'J' is i just cann't understand !! Suggestions??

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

#define MAX 50

char stack[MAX];

int top = -1;

void push(char element)
{
    stack[++top] = element;
}

char pop()
{
    return(stack[top--]);
}

char tope()
{
    return(stack[top]);
}

int prec(char c)
{
    switch(c){
        case '+':
        case '-' : return 1;
                    break;
        case '*' :
        case '/' : return 2;
                   break;
        default:
                   return 0;
                   break;
        }
}

int main()
{

    char post[MAX],in[MAX],ch,element;
    printf("Infix expression : ");
    scanf("%s",in);

    int i=0,k=0;

    in[strlen(in)] = ')';
    push('(');

    while((ch = in[i++]) != '\0')
    {
        if(isalnum(ch))
            post[k++] = ch;
        if(ch == '(') 
            push(ch);
        if(ch == ')')
        {
            while(tope() != '(')
            {
                post[k++] = pop();
            }
            pop();
        }
        if(ch == '+' || ch =='-' || ch == '*' || ch == '/')
        {
            while(prec(ch) <= prec(tope()))
            {
                post[k++] = pop();
            }
            push(ch);
        }
    }
    post[k] = '\0';

    printf("%s",post);

    return 0;




}
```

Comment: Instead of adding `)` to the end of the string, why not just treat the null character like a `)`?

Comment: Yeah Barmar, that's a solution but I wanted to do it in a different way !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
in[strlen(in)] = ')';
```

overwrites the nul-terminating character, which explains strange chars when printing (printing stops only when meeting another nul char by luck: undefined behaviour which may even lead to a crash if no nul char is found in the `in` 50-byte buffer)

You have to shift it, for instance like this:

```
int l = strlen(in);
in[l] = ')';
in[l+1] = '\0';
```

Note: you *have* to store the length of your string in `l` instead of calling `strlen(in)` twice not only because of the performance loss but, because putting the parenthesis means that `strlen` doesn't work properly until you null-terminate.

(also you probably want to protect your `scanf` like this: `scanf("%48s",in);` so you're sure to have enough room for the extra parenthesis for your 50-size buffer, even compatible with your macro definition, see [scanf: template with macro (#define constant) inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409776/scanf-template-with-macro-define-constant-inside))

Comment: Thanks a lot Jean, I was hovering over the same point but was confused as it worked without null character when input don't contain parenthesis !

Comment: Problem still remains!!

Comment: D:\Soft\C\C>a.exe
    Infix expression : 4*(5+3)
    453+*j

Comment: of course! editing my post (I thought it was obvious, apparently not)